# is it possible to colspan in django tables 2

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

is it possible to use colspan in django tables 2? 
I have 5 rows with 4 cols, but i want my second row to be with 1 col colspan=4

How can i do this? Is it possible.

Here is my code:

```
class FavoriteContactTable(FavoriteTable):
    date_added = tables.Column()
    address = AddressColumn(empty_values=(), orderable=False)
    email = tables.EmailColumn(accessor='swimmer.user.email')
    phone = PhoneColumn(empty_values=())

    class Meta:
        model = Favorite
        fields = ('address', 'email', 'phone', 'date_added')
        attrs = {"class": "table table-condensed table-striped table-hover"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to add a `colspan` to a `Column` with:

```
tables.Column(attrs={"td": {"colspan": "4"}})
```

However, this would make all the rows for that column span 4 cells instead of just the second.

Another solution is to override the table template:

```
class FavoriteContactTable(FavoriteTable):
    template = "path_to_template"
```

It should extend [django_tables2/table.html](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/templates/django_tables2/table.html) template and then override the `table.tbody.row` block.

Probably the easiest solution is to do it with jQuery/Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(column_no)").attr("colspan", "4");
});
```

I haven't checked the Javascript but it should be something along those lines.

Comment: tables.Column(attrs={"td": {"colspan": "4"}}) will edit all rows. 
I will try the second option :)